# About Exercise 3.B.18 on p.68 in "Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd Edition" by Sheldon Axler. Is this modification to 3.B.18 good or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

I am reading "Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd Edition" by Sheldon Axler.

> Exercise 3.B.18 on p.68
> Suppose $V$ and $W$ are both finite-dimensional. Prove that there exists a surjective linear map from $V$ to $W$ if and only if $\dim V\geq\dim W$.

When I read the exercise above, I felt it was odd.

I feel the following exercise is better.

By 3.22 Fundamental Theorem of Linear Maps on p.63, if there exists a surjective linear map from a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ to a vector space $W$, then $W$ is finite-dimensional.

> Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional. Prove that there exists a surjective linear map from $V$ to $W$ if and only if $W$ is finite-dimensional and $\dim V\geq\dim W$.

Is this modification good or not?

Comment: The hypothesis that $W$ is finite-dimensional in your modification is redundant in my opinion since if $\dim V\geq \dim W$ and $V$ is finite-dimensional then this immediately implies that $\dim W$ is also finite and hence $W$ is finite-dimensional.

Comment: Equivalently to 3.B.18 you could say: "Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional and $W$ a vector space. Prove that there exists a surjection $f:V\to W$ iff $\dim W\leq \dim V$."

Comment: @ChrisNick92 Thank you very much for your comment. Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional. Prove that there exists a surjective linear map from $V$ to $W$ if and only if $\dim V\geq\dim W$. What do you think this modification?

Comment: @ChrisNick92 Thank you very much for your modification.